# how we can show users in admin panel in django in m2m field without list comprehension

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

```
class Page(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    post = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField()
    def get_user(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])
```

i add this function to get users and added in list-display my question is we use list comprehension how we can do without using list comprehension

```
def get_user(self):return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])
```

is there anyway to do it?

Comment: How would you rather see the user field displayed?

Comment: i want to see same as showing in https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPnYj.png but i want to know how we can do this without list comprehension. i mean how we can do with for loop.

Comment: i add this function to get users and added in list-display my question is we use list comprehension how we can do without using list comprehension `def get_user(self): return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])`

Comment: is there any way to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know how we can do this without list comprehension. i mean how we can do with for loop

Okay, this way:

```py
def get_user(self):
    users = list(self.user.all())
    if len(users) == 0:
        return ""
    users_str = str(users[0])
    for user in users[1:]:
        users_str += ", " + str(user)
    return users_str
```

Not pretty sure why you need it, but it's possible :)

Comment: i got it. Thank You very my much